Copy and Paste Value and formatting in multiple same cells when condition is met
I am a beginner and I am trying to create an Excel Macro to do the following.
When any cell in column AF = "Y", I want to copy and paste Values and number formatting in cell M, T and AM:AO in the same row.
Currently all those cells have formulas in them.
Any help is much appreciated.
Sub PasteContitionalSpecial()

Lastrow = .Range("AF" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("AF" & r).Value = "Y"

Range("M").Copy = Range("M").xlPasteValues

I tried variations of the above with no success.

I think this is what you're trying to do?
Option Explicit

Sub PasteContitionalSpecial()
    
    Dim lastrow As Long, r as long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
        lastrow = .Range("AF" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 2 To lastrow
        
            If .Range("AF" & r).Value = "Y" Then
            
                .Range("M" & r).Value = .Range("M" & r).Value
            
            End If
            
        Next r
        
    End With

End Sub

Some notes:

Always include Option Explicit at the top of your module
Always declare your variables (Dim lastrow As Long)
In general, you want to fully qualify your ranges (ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range()). We should also avoid using active or select references as well.


I was going to comment originally but figured you'd agree with the suggestion.

@dwirony   Thanks for your help. Originally I was getting a 438 run time error but then i copied and pasted your answer again and it seems happy but it doesn't change the formula to the value. Do I need to change "With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet " to the actual names?  I've even tried it in a new workbook with only threes columns, A Data, M = A and AF Y.

You should replace it with the actual names, yes. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetNameHere") for example.

.Range("M" & r).Value = .Range("M" & r).Value will turn formulas into values. Make sure you duplicate that line for any other columns you're trying to do this in.
